# Django, Apache2 and Nginx : Long loading time

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, server, apache2

I use Django as a technology for my website. Let's say that the domain name I use is *example.com*.

I use **Apache2** as my main web server and **Nginx** to serve static files.

I first installed Apache and tested it. It worked perfectly (Without css and other static files, just the html).

I then installed Nginx (I have never used it before today) and this is where I encountered problems. Indeed when I want to access my website I get the html well as before. But the loading continues and the static files are not recovered.
I do not see any error in the Mozilla terminal.

Here is "Site-available" configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_site

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

apache.conf :

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>


# Configuration for Django application
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/my_site/site/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/my_site

<Directory var/www/my_site/my_site>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>   

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# FQDN
ServerName example.com
```

My Nginx config :

```
server {   
     listen   8000;   
     server_name  localhost;

     access_log  /var/log/nginx/aa8000.access.log;    
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/aa8000.error.log;    

       location / {   
           index  index.html index.htm;    
       }    

     location ^/static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        root   /var/www/my_site/allstatic/;    
     }    
 }
```

And to finish my Django setting for static files :

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://example.com:8000/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/my_site/static/',
]
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/my_site/allstatic'
```

Nothing in Nginx error log or even in access log.

**Edit** : Finally I only use apache and it works. 
There is what I added in apache conf:

```
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/my_site/allstatic/favicon/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /var/www/my_site/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/my_site/allstatic/

<Directory /var/www/my_site/allstatic>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/my_site/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I don't understand why ? nginx and apache are created for the same purpose. Use only one. I recommend using nginx

Comment: From official Django Documentation : "Django doesn’t serve files itself; it leaves that job to whichever Web server you choose.

We recommend using a separate Web server – i.e., one that’s not also running Django – for serving media. Here are some good choices:

    Nginx
    A stripped-down version of Apache

If, however, you have no option but to serve media files on the same Apache VirtualHost as Django, you can set up Apache to serve some URLs as static media, and others using the mod_wsgi interface to Django."

Comment: Yup, that's basically what I've said. Use Nginx as high-performance HTTP server and reverse proxy, use uwsgi or gunicorn as a Python WSGI HTTP Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add static (and if you need it, media) sections to your apache file like the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files in your apache.conf

And are you hosting more than one site? If not, don't use the sites-available; just turn off virtual hosting and don't enable anything in the sites-enabled directory.